# URP unity2d How to set order in layer

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I can't figure out how the order in the layer in the URP works. I see the Light order option but it doesn't work the way i want. For example, i need to impose light on wall

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have to make entries in layers and add Sorting Group to UI element.

Sorting Group

[image]

Layers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, i can fixed my problem. If you collision with it case, just set correctly material in Inspector

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).